# How to assign a list of subsript?

Tags: assignment

I want to assign Subscript[C,i] by mapping a specific list.
For example, the list is {1,2,3,4}, and I want to assign 1 to C1, 2 to C2, 3 to C3 and 4 to C4. 
How should I do? Many thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

Just `Map` over the list, like:

```
(Subscript[c, #] = #) & /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: very help! thanks!